# Get location of a swing component

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

I have put some JPanels into another JPanel which its' layout is Box Layout and Y-Axis.
After I have put all the panels I need to get the Y position of each added JPanel in from the JPanel container panel. But, when I try to get that I always get zero for Y position of each JPanel. Please tell me how to get the Y position of each Jpanel from the JPanel container JPanel.

This is what I have done,

```
JPanel panelHolder = new JPanel(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
for(int i = 0; i< 10; i++){
   JPanel p = new JPanel(); 
   panelHolder.add(p);
}

int componentCount = panelHolder.getComponentCount();

for (int j = 0; i < componentCount ; j++) {

  Component c = pnlRowHolder.getComponent(i);
  JPanel p = (JPanel)c;
  System.out.println(p.getY());//I get zero for all
}
```

Comment: Try checking _after_ `validate()` or `pack()`; also, edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that show your approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your `JPanel` to the `JFrame`s *contentPane* thus allowing you to get the X and Y co ordinates using `getX()` and `get()` though I'd suggest adding all components first, as the points may change as more components are added and then as trashgod said simply call `pack()` on the frame instance.

I did a short sample to demonstrate:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test().createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createAndShowUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        initComponents(frame);
        
        frame.pack();//call pack 
        
        printPanelCompPoints(mainPanel);//produces correct coords
        
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel mainPanel;

    private void initComponents(JFrame frame) {
        mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel westPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel eastPanel = new JPanel();

        centerPanel.add(new JLabel("CENTER"));
        northPanel.add(new JLabel("NORTH"));
        eastPanel.add(new JLabel("EAST"));
        southPanel.add(new JLabel("SOUTH"));
        westPanel.add(new JLabel("WEST"));

        mainPanel.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainPanel.add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainPanel.add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        mainPanel.add(eastPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        mainPanel.add(westPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

       frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
    
       printPanelCompPoints(mainPanel);//produces all 0's
    }

    private void printPanelCompPoints(JPanel mainPanel) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mainPanel.getComponentCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println(mainPanel.getComponent(i).getX() + ", " + mainPanel.getComponent(i).getY());
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see calling `printPanelCompPoints(mainPanel);` in `initComponents(JFrame frame)` produces all 0's, (as they have been added to the frame but `pack() has not been called).

> 0, 0
>
> 0, 0
>
> 0, 0
>
> 0, 0
>
> 0, 0

however in the `createAndShowUI()` after calling `pack()` on the `JFrame`s instance calling  `printPanelCompPoints(mainPanel);` produces the correct co-odrinates:

> 44, 26
>
> 0, 0
>
> 0, 52
>
> 99, 26
>
> 0, 26

Answer (score 4):

Coordinates are relative to their parent. In your exemple, all the child components are being added along the top of the parent container, making there y position 0 (relative to their parent).

Try adding an empty border to the parent container, you should see the y position change.

You can use the [`SwingUtilities.convertPoint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#convertPoint%28java.awt.Component,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.Component%29) to convert between coordinate systems

Answer (score 3):

Pack the frame before getting position. It seems everything overlaps each other starting at origin (0,0) until you pack.

Here's a working code:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestBoxLayout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JPanel panelHolder = new JPanel();
        panelHolder.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelHolder, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            JPanel p = new JPanel();
            p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 13)); //I set the height just to make sure.
            panelHolder.add(p);
        }
        frame.add(panelHolder);

        /**
         * Pack before you get the position.
         */
        frame.pack();

        int componentCount = panelHolder.getComponentCount();
        for (int j = 0; j < componentCount; j++) {
            Component c = panelHolder.getComponent(j);
            JPanel p = (JPanel) c;
            System.out.println(p.getY());//I get 0, 13, 26, 39, .....
        }

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
0
13
26
39
52
65
78
91
104
117
```

**Note**: The signature for BoxLayout is `BoxLayout(Container target, int axis)`. The `target` is the stuff you are setting your layout to. For this reason, if you want use a BoxLayout, you should always create the panel first. Then use `component.setLayout()` so that the target already exists. The `this` in your JPanel constructor was referring to something else, not `panelHolder`. I guess the class you created this function in is also a subclass of `Container` and that is why you didn't get an error.

Comment: +1 so close to the true, [but by default isn9t there the reason to set XxxSize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)

Comment: @mKorbel Usually, I let the layout manager organize the preferred sizes of components. I only used `setPreferredSize` just to test with a different number. Without that, I got `0,10,20,...` which is still correct.

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand what you are asking.

Comment: I understand the question and i responded to it. Why don't you make your point directly let me know where you think I am making a mistake?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have Jpanel father that contains a JPanel son. If cx is the coordinate x of the son with respect to the father and cy is the coordinate y of the son with respect to the father, then:

cx = son.getLocationOnScreen().getX()-father.getLocationOnScreen().getX()

cy = son.getLocationOnScreen().getY()-father.getLocationOnScreen().getY()

I think is the easiest way...

Answer (score 1):

> Please tell me how to get the Y position of each Jpanel from the JPanel container JPanel.

- `BoxLayout` accepting `XxxSize` (`Preferred` in this case) that returns its child,
- `JPanel` returns (0, 0) this is correct value
- this or simlair result you can get from all `LayoutManager`, for example built_in `FlowLayout` for `JPanel` (accepting only the `PreferredSiz`e), returns the same coordinates `(0, 0)`
- excepting `BorderLayout` then is there generated `10pixels`(for W, E, N, S areas), and valid only in the case that `CENTER area` is used for some `JComponent`
- `JPanel` is `Container` and by empty `JPanel` by defualt returns zero size on the screen,
- `JPanel` can to returns proper coordinates if is there any `JComponent` or you override `XxxSize` in the `JPanel` constructor

Answer (score 0):

The problem is often that the layout or the drawing is done only after the whole method returned. In that case, `getX` and `getY` return 0.

It may help to call `pack()` on the frame window, or `doLayout()` or `validate()` on the JPanel you are working on. But often it doesn't help, because you have little influence on the internal scheduling:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html

What does help me in this case is to put the part where I need the X and Y location into a worker thread:

```
JPanel panelHolder = new JPanel(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
for(int i = 0; i< 10; i++){
    JPanel p = new JPanel(); 
    panelHolder.add(p);
}

int componentCount = panelHolder.getComponentCount();

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {         
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int j = 0; i < componentCount; j++) {    
            Component c = pnlRowHolder.getComponent(i);
            JPanel p = (JPanel) c;
            System.out.println(p.getY());
        }
    }
});
```

This way getting the X and Y will be postponed until the layout is done.