# Getting position of Component in Swing

Tags: java, swing

I have a JTable that's buried in my UI. I get a `Rectangle` object for one of my cells. From what I understand, this cells `Rectangle` (aka bounds) are relative to its container (a `JPanel`).

What I need is this rectangles location relative to its containing JFrame. I am aware of

```
SwingUtilities.convertPoint(Component source,
                                 Point aPoint,
                                 Component destination)
```

And I call it like so:

```
SwingUtilities.convertPoint(jtable,
                            tableCellRectangle.getLocation(),
                            jframe);
```

The converted point however is not correct. I am thinking passing in the jtable is not correct. I am not sure what exactly to pass in for the first parameter. Can anyone provide insight how I can convert my point?

Comment: *"From what I understand, this cells Rectangle (aka bounds) are relative to its container (a JPanel)"* - To the `JTable`. *"The converted point however is not correct. I am thinking passing in the jtable is not correct. Can anyone provide insight how I can convert my point?"* - Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Maybe this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589824/get-location-of-a-swing-component

Comment: *"Getting position of Component in Swing"* ...why?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Because I am painting something above it